# Prove $2\sin2nx\cos x=\sin(2n+1)x+\sin(2n-1)x$

Tags: trigonometry

$$2\sin2nx\cos x=\sin(2n+1)x+\sin(2n-1)x$$
Where $n\in\Bbb N$ and $x$ is arbitrary.

Comment: What have you tried? And this is merely an application of the sum-to-product formula.

Comment: I would clarify that it's $\sin\left(\left(2n+1\right)x\right)$

Comment: $2 \sin x \cos x = \sin 2x$, but I don't know what to do with the $2n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*

Use this twice $$\sin(a+b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)+\cos(a)\sin(b)$$
with $a=2nx$ and $b=\pm x$, and add the results together.

Comment: Oh, now I realize how straightforward is this. Thanks!